# What is wrong with my GSON parsing in Android?

Tags: android, json, gson

The code below throws NullPointerException at Collections.sort(mHomeworks), even though I am able to retrieve the JSON string at Log.d("Check",jsonInfo). Is there something wrong with my parsing?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String jsonInfo = settings.getString("Homeworks", null);
    Type listOfHomework = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Homework>>(){}.getType();
    if(jsonInfo != null) {
        mHomeworks = (ArrayList<Homework>)gson.fromJson(jsonInfo, listOfHomework);
        /*JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(jsonInfo).getAsJsonArray();
        mHomeworks.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i<array.size();i++){
            mHomeworks.add(gson.fromJson(array.get(i),Homework.class));
        }*/
        Log.d("Check", mHomeworks.getClass() + "");
        Log.d("Check",mHomeworks.get(0).getClass()+"");
        Log.d("Check", mHomeworks.size() + "");
        Log.d("Check",jsonInfo);
        for (int i=0;i<mHomeworks.size();i++) {
            Log.d("Check", mHomeworks.get(i).getDueDate().getTimeInMillis() + "");
        }
    }
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null){
        newHomework = intent.getParcelableExtra(NEW_HOMEWORK);
        mHomeworks.add(newHomework);
    }
    adapter = new HomeworkAdapter(this, R.layout.homework_row,mHomeworks);
    Collections.sort(mHomeworks);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

If you need it, this is the Homework class:

```
public class Homework implements Parcelable,Comparable<Homework>{
private String mName;
private String mSubject;
private boolean mCompleted;
private Calendar mDueDate;
private Calendar mRemindDate;

public int describeContents(){return 0;}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags){
    dest.writeString(mName);
    dest.writeString(mSubject);
    dest.writeValue(mCompleted);
    dest.writeSerializable(mDueDate);
    dest.writeSerializable(mRemindDate);
}

private Homework(Parcel in){
    mName = in.readString();
    mSubject = in.readString();
    mCompleted = (Boolean) in.readValue(null);
    mDueDate = (Calendar) in.readSerializable();
    mRemindDate = (Calendar) in.readSerializable();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Homework> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Homework>(){
    public Homework createFromParcel(Parcel in){
        return new Homework(in);
    }
    public Homework[] newArray(int size){return new Homework[size];}
};

public Homework(String name, String subject, Calendar dueDate){//Constructor
    mName = name;
    mSubject = subject;
    mCompleted = false;
    mDueDate = dueDate;
    mRemindDate = dueDate;
}
public Homework(String name, String subject, Calendar dueDate, Calendar remindDate){//Alternate constructor
    mName = name;
    mSubject = subject;
    mCompleted = false;
    mDueDate = dueDate;
    mRemindDate = remindDate;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Homework compareHW){
    Calendar compareDate = compareHW.getDueDate();
    return getDueDate().compareTo(compareDate);
}

//Getters and setters.
public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public Calendar getRemindDate() {
    return mRemindDate;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return mSubject;
}

public boolean isCompleted() {
    return mCompleted;
}

public Calendar getDueDate() {
    return mDueDate;
}

public void setDueDate(Calendar date){
    mDueDate = date;
}

public void setRemindDate(Calendar remindDate){
    mRemindDate = remindDate;
}

public void setCompleted(boolean completed){
    mCompleted = completed;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'd like to add that it works as a data preserver when I close the app then restart it from Android Studio. However, if I close the app then reopen it in the emulator, that is when it fails.

EDIT: JSON String as logged is:

```
[
    {
        "mDueDate": {
            "year": 2015,
            "month": 3,
            "dayOfMonth": 28,
            "hourOfDay": 0,
            "minute": 0,
            "second": 0
        },
        "mName": "CEP HW3",
        "mRemindDate": {
            "year": 2015,
            "month": 3,
            "dayOfMonth": 28,
            "hourOfDay": 0,
            "minute": 0,
            "second": 0
        },
        "mSubject": "CEP",
        "mCompleted": false
    },
    {
        "mDueDate": {
            "year": 2015,
            "month": 4,
            "dayOfMonth": 8,
            "hourOfDay": 12,
            "minute": 0,
            "second": 0
        },
        "mName": "Please plz",
        "mRemindDate": {
            "year": 2015,
            "month": 4,
            "dayOfMonth": 8,
            "hourOfDay": 12,
            "minute": 0,
            "second": 0
        },
        "mSubject": "lol",
        "mCompleted": false
    },
    {
        "mDueDate": {
            "year": 2015,
            "month": 4,
            "dayOfMonth": 21,
            "hourOfDay": 0,
            "minute": 0,
            "second": 0
        },
        "mName": "CEP HW2",
        "mRemindDate": {
            "year": 2015,
            "month": 4,
            "dayOfMonth": 21,
            "hourOfDay": 0,
            "minute": 0,
            "second": 0
        },
        "mSubject": "CEP",
        "mCompleted": false
    },
    {
        "mDueDate": {
            "year": 2015,
            "month": 10,
            "dayOfMonth": 18,
            "hourOfDay": 0,
            "minute": 0,
            "second": 0
        },
        "mName": "Don't mess up",
        "mRemindDate": {
            "year": 2015,
            "month": 9,
            "dayOfMonth": 16,
            "hourOfDay": 12,
            "minute": 0,
            "second": 0
        },
        "mSubject": "English",
        "mCompleted": false
    }
]
```

Stack Trace:

```
05-02 03:12:19.445    2382-2382/patton.hwtracker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: patton.hwtracker, PID: 2382
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{patton.hwtracker/patton.hwtracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:291)
        at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:153)
        at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:142)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1957)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1864)
        at patton.hwtracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:122)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: a/ post the json content. b/ how do you tell gson how to deserialize your calendar objects?

Comment: I haven't told gson how to do it. Should I?

Comment: not sure. How do you create the json? (also, run in debug mode, set a breakpoint in the compare method, and you should see what is null there. probably the Calendar)

Comment: I wish. Setting a breakpoint at the Collections.sort and stepping into it, I find that the date items are all GregorianCalendars. No nulls.

Comment: ok. let's get back to the basics. post your stacktrace, and step into the exception to see what exactly is null

Comment: Done. However, I can't step into the exception. As stated above, the Exception is only thrown when I start the app from the emulator. If I run the app (in or out of debug mode) from Android Studio, it works fine.

Comment: what this indicates is that one of the objects in the array is null for some reason

Comment: I am stumped as to why that would be the case.

Comment: could this one `newHomework = intent.getParcelableExtra(NEW_HOMEWORK);` be null?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Json conversion is correct but you're incorrectly trying to pull the homework out of your bundle.

Try changing:

```
if(intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null){
    newHomework = intent.getParcelableExtra(NEW_HOMEWORK);
    mHomeworks.add(newHomework);
}
```

to:

```
if(intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null){
    newHomework = (Homework)  intent.getExtras().getParcelable(NEW_HOMEWORK);
    mHomeworks.add(newHomework);
}
```

Comment: Both versions work fine. This part of the code is not related to persistent data, it is actually about another activity that is used to add a Homework. This is how I get a new Homework if MainActivity is intented by that activity.